# Auto scrolling page within iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scroll

I would like to show a web page on a monitor, that when loaded scrolls automatically until the end without any interaction.

Any idea on how I can achieve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `window.scrollTo` at the end of the body like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>
<p>page content</p>


</body>
<script>
window.scrollTo({ left: 0, top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth" });
</script>
</html>
```

please click on run code to see result